# How to prevent element is detached from the DOM errors?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, primefaces, cypress

We have a timing problem with cypress/jsf and two PrimeFaces-Autocompletes. Our input of facility depends on the selected element. When an element is selected an ajax request is sent and the facility field is updated. (see code example below - xhtml)

Our cypress test first selects an element and then wants to select a facility. However, the facility input field cannot be cleared because it is detached from the DOM. The error message is: "CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.clear() failed because this element is detached from the DOM." We already wait for the ajax request (with cy.route) but the problem still occurs. (see code example below - javascript)

How can we prevent detach-errors with dependent input fields?

```
<!-- element -->
<p:outputLabel id="elementLabel" for="element" value="#{i18n.element}" />
<p:autoComplete id="element" value="#{bean.selectedElement}"
                  dropdown="true"completeMethod="#{bean.completeElement}"
                  var="element" itemValue="#{element}" itemLabel="#{element}">
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{bean.updateFacility()}" 
    partialSubmit="true" process="@this" update="facility"/>
</p:autoComplete>

<!-- facility -->
<p:outputLabel id="facilityLabel" for="facility" value="#{i18n.facility}" />
<p:autoComplete id="facility" value="#{bean.selectedFacility}" required="false"
                dropdown="true" completeMethod="#{bean.completeFacility}"
                var="facility" itemValue="#{facility}" itemLabel="#{facility}" >
</p:autoComplete>
```

Javascript:

```
cy.route({
    method: 'POST', url: '/app/dummy.xhtml'
}).as('request')
cy.selectOptionLoadingAlias('#element_input', '#element_1', '@request')
cy.selectOptionLoadingAlias('#facility_input', '#facility_1', '@request')

Cypress.Commands.add("selectOptionLoadingAlias", (inputField, selectOption, alias) => {
    cy.get(inputField).should('be.visible').clear().type('Dummy 1')

    cy.wait(alias).then((xhr) => { 
        // we checked that xhr is the correct request (update for element/facility)
        cy.get(selectOption).click()
        cy.get(selectOption).should('not.be.visible')
    })
})
```

Comment: I can't help you in relation to cypress but i had the same problem while developing primefaces-selenium (https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-selenium).    
When i lookup a "plain" selenium element, do an AJAX update afterwards and try to use it -> i got a "detached element" exception.  
I solved this to always get proxy element, which lazy lookups the component on each method call like `click()`. Maybe there is something similar in cypress like a element proxy or lazy mechanism.

Comment: Can you try to this line instead? `cy.get(inputField).should('be.visible').clear().type('Dummy 1').parent()`

Comment: @tandraschko I think there is no known element proxy or lazy mechanism in cypress. "cy.get" should be a lazy fetching mechanism.

We tried:
cy.get(inputField).should("be.visible");
cy.get(inputField).clear();
cy.get(inputField).type(searchField);

The code above didn't work (same problem).

Comment: @ManuelAbascal We tried adding ".parent()" but it didn't solve our issue.

Comment: I just had to implement cypress-retries reciepe, since this seem to happen quite random irrespective of the type of element. With retries, cypress would simply retry and pass in  that

Comment: @Emjey Could you provide an example?

Comment: @wEight Cypress comes with default retries now with version 5.0.0 . All you have to do is enable this feature in the `cypress.json` like 

```{ env: {retries: {openMode: 1, runMode:3 }} }```

This should take care of retrying in case of failed test due to intermittent errors including the above

More information on this link https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/test-retries.html

Comment: @Emjey Waiting sure paid off. Hooray for the new update(s). :))

Comment: @grid-tester : Is your problem solved with the retries feature?

Comment: @AtulKumarSharma i dont think retries will fix the DOM detatched errors from occuring, it will only re-run that scenario as usually these errors are intermittent and yes in all times the DOM detatched errors get resolved on retry unless the failure is valid

Comment: @grid-tester: you tried cy.wait() or cy.waitFor()?

Answer (score 0):

Try below fix to the clear section, the click trick should assure element won't be detached:

```
cy.get(inputField).click({force:true}).clear().type('Dummy 1');
```